# Zurb Foundation javascript reInit module not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation

i'm ajaxifying a website. My menu should always be sticky (using the sticky module provided by Foundation). But it is only sticky on a regular page load, and not on ajax reload (aka when navigating on the website)
I'm trying to re-initialise the module when the event `ajaxComplete` happens, using the line provided in the documentation of Foundation 6:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    Foundation.reInit($('.sticky'));
    //other code
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work, because I get this error in the console :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_init' of undefined
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (foundation.core.js:103)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?ver=2.1.0:2)
    at o.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js?ver=2.1.0:2)
    at Object.reInit (foundation.core.js:102)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (stickyfooter.js:28)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=2.1.0:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.min.js?ver=2.1.0:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js?ver=2.1.0:3)
    at x (jquery.min.js?ver=2.1.0:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js?ver=2.1.0:4)
```

Which I don't understand. What does it mean ? How can I make the module work after an ajax reload ?
The website in action : http://lesdeuxvagues.com/demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it's apparently a known issue in zurb-foundation, the sticky module doesn't work after being destroyed (though I don't know why it's destroyed in my case because i'm only reloading other content with AJAX), all the other foundation js plugin seem to be working though. (see : https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/9047) 

The solution that I will try is to just find another sticky library to take care of this particular issue.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post your markup, but I visited the site and don't see a ".sticky" class in your CSS.  You are calling

```
    Foundation.reInit()
```

on a jQuery selector.  So does

```
    $('.sticky')
```

select anything on your page?  Why don't you try:

```
       Foundation.reInit($('[data-sticky]'))
```

which would reinitialize all the elements with attribute data-sticky

Comment: The header, which also has the id `#masthead` has the class sticky! I applied this line `$('.sticky').css('border', '2px solid red');` inside `ajaxComplete`, and it does show a red border !
Sorry for not posting the markup, it's pretty long so I don't really know which part would be relevant ! I tried data-sticky and get the same error as before `TypeError: Cannot read property '_init' of undefined`

Comment: When I load the page from your URL, the header is sticky (except on small screens...you need to add 

         `stickyOn: small`

to the data-options.  It stays sticky until you click a button - that's when the error comes up.  But then you are navigating to a new page, so you need to call 

        `$(document).foundation()`

instead of `reInit()`

Comment: Oh thanks for the `stickyOn: small`, i meant to fix this issue too ! Weirdly enough, I add tried to call `$(document).foundation()`, but it doesn't work either, and I don't even get an error in the console, so I have no idea where it goes wrong.. I figure, that maybe, because my element already as a `data-sticky` attribute before `ajaxComplete` it's not getting initialised again? (hence the `reInit()` try) but obviously i'm wrong somewhere !

Comment: Do you have any other idea @genestd ?